# What type of NLP method to choose?

Tags: facebook, nlp, lexical-analysis, sentiment-analysis

so I'm going to build a prototype of a Social Web application that:
- Incorporates Facebook data of users (working hours, house and work office)
to create a web app so that friends and friends of friends that have similar routes can drive/bike with each other.

However, in order for this app to be useful it should be able to extract keywords (e.g. working hours, or if someone has to work later (and he/she posts this on Facebook). Now I'm reading a lot of methods but I don't know which one to choose:
 - Sentiment analysis
 - Lexical analysis 
 - Syntactic parsing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately what you want is a human-like intelligence that can read between the lines of all the posts to extract information.  So, in general terms, you have the same Too Hard (currently) problem that everyone else in every branch of NLP faces. I'm just pointing that out because then you realize your question becomes which imperfect approximation should I use.

Personally, I'd start with a simple text matcher. Look for strings like "Starting work today at 9". Gather your core list of sentences.

Then you realize there are variations due to rephrasing. "Start work today at 9", "Starting today at 9", "9 is my start time today", etc. Bring in a sentence analyzer at this point, and instead of a string of ascii codes the sentence turns into a string of nouns, adjectives and verbs.

You also have synonyms: "Starting my job today at 9", "Starting down the office today at 9", "Starting work today an hour later than normal". WordNet (and semantic networks generally) can help a bit. The last example there, though, not only requires parsing a fairly complicated clause, but also knowing their usual start time is 8. (Oh, on all the above you needed to know if they meant 9am or 9pm...)

By this point you realize you are gathering lots of fuzzy data. That is when you bring in some machine learning, to try have it take care of discovering for you that one combination of the verb "start", the noun "work", the time-noun "today" and the number "9" is useful to you, and another isn't (e.g. "At work today learnt that new drama starts at 9. Forgot to set recorder. Aaarrggh!")

Comment: What about social mining tools? Aren't there any useful keyword extraction tools out there for analysing, for instance a Facebook snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a customized Name Entity Recognizer. NLTK could be a good starting point. However, the default NE chunker in NLTK is a maximum entropy chunker trained on the ACE corpus and has not been trained to recognize dates and times. So you need to train your own classifier if you want to do that.

The link below gives a neat and detailed explanation for the same.

> http://mattshomepage.com/articles/2016/May/23/nltk_nec/

Also, there is a module called timex in nltk_contrib which might help you with your needs.

> https://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/timex.py

Cheers!